# How to stop one specific user to delete his account in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in /views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<b>Cancel my account</b>
<%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %>.
```

which allows the logged in user to delete his account. Now I do NOT want one user with id=223 to have this permission/link. How can I do this ? I am not not sure the below cod in edit.html.erb file will work (or is there any better way to do it?)

EDIT - Ok this below code is working but how to do it through controller ?

```
<% if current_user.id != 223 %>
<b>Cancel my account</b>
    <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %>.
<% end %>
```

Comment: Don't do this. Using id == x is bad. What if the database is reseeded? What if you now have two users you want to exclude? Use a model level (or even DB level) property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller has nothing to do with a link being displayed or not. However you can disable the deletion in the controller by checking the same condition.

Anyways, you should create at least a model property for this. This id hardcode thingy is not nice, so hide it at least and make it not being repeated.

```
model User
  ...

  def can_delete_account?
    id != 223  # ugly hack
  end

end
```

Comment: Hi @Matzi - can you explain "Anyways, you should create at least a model property for this" how to do this ?

Comment: thanks, so in views, I just need to call <% can_delete_account %> ... ... <% end %> ? right ?

Comment: also @Matzi, what if there are 2 accounts ? say id 223 and 224 ? will "id != 223 && id!=224" work ?

Comment: It will. But you can use `[223, 224].include?(id)`. Best solution would be to mark the undeletable records somehow.